# Recording on Android for iPhone playback works sometimes

Tags: android, ios, android-7.0-nougat, android-mediarecorder

*please don't flame as a duplicate as it is different from posts I have found and adds a clue to a working solution*

I have written code (see below) in Android Studio to record audio to file and it works well. A well documented issue is that the files won't play on iPhone as they aren't actually mp3 files, rather mp4. If you use the file extension .m4a it works on iPhone not on Android (and some online email previewers). My dev was on 5.0.1 Lollipop (Samsung S4) and 4.4 KitKat.

I had given up hope on finding a single file solution, but then tried running my code on an LG K8 2017 running 7.0 Nougat. Much to my surprise the iPhone could play files recorded there. I wondered if this was a change to Android that made this possible. I have tried the same code on 6.0 Marshmallow (Alcatel U3) but it doesn't play on iPhone. I don't have any other phones to try.

I am left wondering the following:

- Would it work on all 7.0 Nougat and later phones?
- Is it specific to something about the LG K8 2017's hardware / software (was fresh from box)?
- Is the change something specific to an atom that I could therefore 'fix' in a file recorded on another phone?

I'm a novice when it comes to MP4, but looking at the atoms I can see quite some differences (e.g. the LG K8 is the only one with moov.udta.auth and moov.udta.type atoms).

My emulator is too slow to investigate this there unfortunately.

```
String mFileName = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "audio.mp3";
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

//mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER); 
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16000);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);

mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
/* ....... */
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.reset();
mRecorder.release();
```